# Group by in Elastica PHP?

Tags: php, elasticsearch, elastica

There's absolutely no documentation about a group by in Elastica. Any idea if such aggregation exists?

I've seen that it's possible to do it using a raw query, but I can't combine raw query results with my results written like this

```
$bool_sub = new \Elastica\Query\Bool();
$bool->addMust($bool_sub);
$query->setFilter($bool);
```

And in any case, group by, by Elasticsearch documentation, counts the results depending on one criteria, but what I want to do is an SQL like group by, where the goal is to combine all identical rows.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. You have to use method `addAggregation`.

For example `elasticsearch` query:

```
{
    "aggs" : {
        "genders" : {
            "terms" : { "field" : "gender" }
        }
    }
}
```

Looks in `elastica` like this:

```
use Elastica\Aggregation\Terms;
use Elastica\Query;

// set up the aggregation
$termsAgg = new Terms("genders");
$termsAgg->setField("gender");

// add the aggregation to a Query object
$query = new Query();
$query->addAggregation($termsAgg);

// retrieve the results
$index = $elasticaClient->getIndex('someindex');
$buckets = $index->search($query)->getAggregation("genders");
```

Comment: Vladimir Kovpak the group by doesn't take into consideration the query filters. It just groups everything alright but how can I make it take the filters of my query into consideration?